# How to filter documents on mongodb based on reference populated subdocuments?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to grab documents based on populated subdocuments.

Here are my models

```
// User model

    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     username: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
     firstName: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
     lastName: {type: String, required: true, lowercase: true},
     phone: {type: String, required: false},
     email: {type: String, required: true},
     password: {type: String, required: true},
     blogs: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blogs'}
    }, {timestamps: true});


// Blog Model

    var BlogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     description: String,
     tags: [String],
     other: [Object],
    }, {timestamps: true});
```

This is how I am grabbing documents

```
  fetchAllByFilter: async function(req, res) {
      try {
          let result = await Users.find({}).populate('blog');
          return res.status(200).send(result);
      }  catch (err) {
          return res.status(200).send({error: err});
      }
    },
```

Now my main question is, how would I grab Users based on their Blogs referenced documents?

For example, Find Users with Blogs that has `Blog.tags` of "food", "cars", "movies" and/or `Blog.other` of `[{...SomeObject}, {...SomeOtherObject}]`

Answer (score 1):

looking at mongo docs [match an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#match-an-array), you could make a utility function somewhat like this...

```
async function findByTag(tag) {
    const blogIds = await Blog.find({ tags: tag }).select("_id");

    const users = await User.find({
        blogs: { $in: blogIds.map((blog) => blog._id) }
    }).populate("blog");
}
```